# ModalPopup running slow when published. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have a modalpopup that open when i click an image in a listview, it runs smoothly and opens fine in local debug mode. But when i publish it, it takes 20 secs approx to open. Can anyone help me please?

The PopUp Code:

http://codepad.org/bId1cy7c

The c# run when click on the image:

http://codepad.org/lWOSKBJJ

Comment: Actually, following some tests. I have found out that it may be due to the listview. As any image or button i click on which is in the listview, runs really slowly

Answer (score 0):

In button click the page might be reloading for post back since you written the popup.show() inside the button click event. You can use another update panel for this button so that the complete page reload can be avoided. Please make a try.